# Anybody compiled mimetic for iOS

Tags: ios, cross-compiling, mime-message, multipartentity

I want to create a mime / multipart parser for IMAP messages. I got few links which says [mimetic](http://www.codesink.org/mimetic_mime_library.html) can do this, but I am unable to compile it for iOS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's old post. But maybe it will help somebody

How I built mimetic in my project (shell-script).

```
# Building mimetic
pushd mimetic

 # i368
 export CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc"
 export CXX="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++"
 export AR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar"
 export CFLAGS="-pipe -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -fpascal-strings -fmessage-length=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -arch i386 -O2 -fPIC -DDARWIN_NO_CARBON -Wall -W"
 export CXXFLAGS="-pipe -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -fpascal-strings -fmessage-length=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -arch i386 -O2 -fPIC -DDARWIN_NO_CARBON -Wall -W"
 mkdir build_i386
 pushd build_i386
  ../configure -prefix=`pwd`
  make clean
  pushd mimetic
   make || exit 1
   make install
  popd
 popd

 # armv7
 export CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc"
 export CXX="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++"
 export AR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar"
 export CFLAGS="-pipe -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -fpascal-strings -fmessage-length=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -arch armv7 -mthumb -O2 -fPIC -Wall -W -DDARWIN_NO_CARBON -D__ARM_ARCH_7__ -D__MARM_THUMB__ -D__ARM_NEON__"
 export CXXFLAGS="-pipe -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -fpascal-strings -fmessage-length=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -arch armv7 -mthumb -O2 -fPIC -Wall -W -DDARWIN_NO_CARBON -D__ARM_ARCH_7__ -D__MARM_THUMB__ -D__ARM_NEON__"
 mkdir build_armv7
 pushd build_armv7
  ../configure --host=i386 --prefix=`pwd`
  make clean 
  pushd mimetic
   make || exit 1
   make install
  popd
 popd

 # bundle
 lipo build_i386/lib/libmimetic.a build_armv7/lib/libmimetic.a  -create -output libmimetic.a

popd
```

Comment: btw.. I took mimetic from Fedora's srpm.

There were next patches:
 mimetic-0.9.2-noconfigh.patch
 mimetic-0.9.7-gcc47.patch
 undef-op.patch

Answer (score 2):

Please find an updated build script for mimetic C++ library for iOS.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$(tput setaf 2)"
echo "###################################################################"
echo "# Preparing to build libmimetic"
echo "###################################################################"
echo "$(tput sgr0)"

JOBS=$(sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu)
# The results will be stored relative to the location
# where you stored this script, **not** relative to
# the location of the protobuf git repo.
PREFIX=`pwd`/libmimetic
if [ -d ${PREFIX} ]
then
    rm -rf "${PREFIX}"
fi
mkdir -p "${PREFIX}/platform"

# A "YES" value will build the latest code from GitHub on the master branch.
# A "NO" value will use the tarball downloaded from ...
USE_GIT_MASTER=NO

MIMETIC_GIT_DIRNAME=mimetic
MIMETIC_VERSION=0.9.8
MIMETIC_RELEASE_URL=http://www.codesink.org/download/mimetic-${MIMETIC_VERSION}.tar.gz
MIMETIC_RELEASE_DIRNAME=mimetic-${MIMETIC_VERSION}
LIBMIMETIC=libmimetic

BUILD_MACOSX_X86_64=YES

BUILD_I386_IOSSIM=YES
BUILD_X86_64_IOSSIM=YES

BUILD_IOS_ARMV7=YES
BUILD_IOS_ARMV7S=YES
BUILD_IOS_ARM64=YES

MIMETIC_SRC_DIR=/tmp/mimetic

DARWIN=darwin`uname -r`

XCODEDIR=`xcode-select --print-path`
IOS_SDK_VERSION=`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-version`
MIN_SDK_VERSION=6.0

MACOSX_PLATFORM=${XCODEDIR}/Platforms/MacOSX.platform
MACOSX_SYSROOT=${MACOSX_PLATFORM}/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk

IPHONEOS_PLATFORM=`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-path`
IPHONEOS_SYSROOT=`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path`

IPHONESIMULATOR_PLATFORM=`xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-platform-path`
IPHONESIMULATOR_SYSROOT=`xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path`

# Uncomment if you want to see more information about each invocation
# of clang as the builds proceed.
# CLANG_VERBOSE="--verbose"

CC="xcrun clang"
CXX="xcrun clang"

CFLAGS="${CLANG_VERBOSE} -DNDEBUG -g -O0 -pipe -fPIC -fcxx-exceptions"
CXXFLAGS="${CLANG_VERBOSE} ${CFLAGS} -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++"

LDFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++"
LIBS="-lc++ -lc++abi"

echo "PREFIX ..................... ${PREFIX}"
echo "USE_GIT_MASTER ............. ${USE_GIT_MASTER}"
echo "MIMETIC_GIT_DIRNAME ....... ${MIMETIC_GIT_DIRNAME}"
echo "MIMETIC_VERSION ........... ${MIMETIC_VERSION}"
echo "MIMETIC_RELEASE_URL ....... ${MIMETIC_RELEASE_URL}"
echo "MIMETIC_RELEASE_DIRNAME ... ${MIMETIC_RELEASE_DIRNAME}"
echo "BUILD_MACOSX_X86_64 ........ ${BUILD_MACOSX_X86_64}"
echo "BUILD_I386_IOSSIM .......... ${BUILD_I386_IOSSIM}"
echo "BUILD_X86_64_IOSSIM ........ ${BUILD_X86_64_IOSSIM}"
echo "BUILD_IOS_ARMV7 ............ ${BUILD_IOS_ARMV7}"
echo "BUILD_IOS_ARMV7S ........... ${BUILD_IOS_ARMV7S}"
echo "BUILD_IOS_ARM64 ............ ${BUILD_IOS_ARM64}"
echo "MIMETIC_SRC_DIR ........... ${MIMETIC_SRC_DIR}"
echo "DARWIN ..................... ${DARWIN}"
echo "XCODEDIR ................... ${XCODEDIR}"
echo "IOS_SDK_VERSION ............ ${IOS_SDK_VERSION}"
echo "MIN_SDK_VERSION ............ ${MIN_SDK_VERSION}"
echo "MACOSX_PLATFORM ............ ${MACOSX_PLATFORM}"
echo "MACOSX_SYSROOT ............. ${MACOSX_SYSROOT}"
echo "IPHONEOS_PLATFORM .......... ${IPHONEOS_PLATFORM}"
echo "IPHONEOS_SYSROOT ........... ${IPHONEOS_SYSROOT}"
echo "IPHONESIMULATOR_PLATFORM ... ${IPHONESIMULATOR_PLATFORM}"
echo "IPHONESIMULATOR_SYSROOT .... ${IPHONESIMULATOR_SYSROOT}"
echo "CC ......................... ${CC}"
echo "CFLAGS ..................... ${CFLAGS}"
echo "CXX ........................ ${CXX}"
echo "CXXFLAGS ................... ${CXXFLAGS}"
echo "LDFLAGS .................... ${LDFLAGS}"
echo "LIBS ....................... ${LIBS}"

while true; do
    read -p "Proceed with build? (y/n) " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done

echo "$(tput setaf 2)"
echo "###################################################################"
echo "# Fetch Mimetic"
echo "###################################################################"
echo "$(tput sgr0)"

(
    if [ -d ${MIMETIC_SRC_DIR} ]
    then
        rm -rf ${MIMETIC_SRC_DIR}
    fi

    cd `dirname ${MIMETIC_SRC_DIR}`

    if [ -d ${MIMETIC_RELEASE_DIRNAME} ]
    then
        rm -rf "${MIMETIC_RELEASE_DIRNAME}"
    fi
    curl --location ${MIMETIC_RELEASE_URL} --output ${MIMETIC_RELEASE_DIRNAME}.tar.gz
    tar xvf ${MIMETIC_RELEASE_DIRNAME}.tar.gz
    mv "${MIMETIC_RELEASE_DIRNAME}" "${MIMETIC_SRC_DIR}"
    rm ${MIMETIC_RELEASE_DIRNAME}.tar.gz
    cd ${MIMETIC_SRC_DIR}
    sed -i '' '/test\/Makefile/d' configure.in
sed -i '' '/test win32/ c\
SUBDIRS = mimetic
' /tmp/mimetic/Makefile.in
)

echo "$(tput setaf 2)"
echo "###################################################################"
echo "# x86_64 for Mac OS X"
echo "###################################################################"
echo "$(tput sgr0)"

if [ "${BUILD_MACOSX_X86_64}" == "YES" ]
then
    (
        cd ${MIMETIC_SRC_DIR}
        make distclean
        ./configure --disable-shared --prefix=${PREFIX} --exec-prefix=${PREFIX}/platform/x86_64-mac "CC=${CC}" "CFLAGS=${CFLAGS} -arch x86_64" "CXX=${CXX}" "CXXFLAGS=${CXXFLAGS} -arch x86_64" "LDFLAGS=${LDFLAGS}" "LIBS=${LIBS}"
        make -j${JOBS}
#        make check
        make install
    )
fi

MIMETICC=${PREFIX}/platform/x86_64-mac/bin/mimetic

###################################################################
# This section contains the build commands for each of the
# architectures that will be included in the universal binaries.
###################################################################

echo "$(tput setaf 2)"
echo "###########################"
echo "# i386 for iPhone Simulator"
echo "###########################"
echo "$(tput sgr0)"

if [ "${BUILD_I386_IOSSIM}" == "YES" ]
then
    (
        cd ${MIMETIC_SRC_DIR}
        make distclean
        ./configure --build=x86_64-apple-${DARWIN} --host=i386-apple-${DARWIN} --disable-shared --prefix=${PREFIX} --exec-prefix=${PREFIX}/platform/i386-sim "CC=${CC}" "CFLAGS=${CFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} -arch i386 -isysroot ${IPHONESIMULATOR_SYSROOT}" "CXX=${CXX}" "CXXFLAGS=${CXXFLAGS} -arch i386 -isysroot ${IPHONESIMULATOR_SYSROOT}" LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} ${LDFLAGS}" "LIBS=${LIBS}"
        make -j${JOBS}
        make install
    )
fi

echo "$(tput setaf 2)"
echo "#############################"
echo "# x86_64 for iPhone Simulator"
echo "#############################"
echo "$(tput sgr0)"

if [ "${BUILD_X86_64_IOSSIM}" == "YES" ]
then
    (
        cd ${MIMETIC_SRC_DIR}
        make distclean
        ./configure --build=x86_64-apple-${DARWIN} --host=x86_64-apple-${DARWIN} --disable-shared --prefix=${PREFIX} --exec-prefix=${PREFIX}/platform/x86_64-sim "CC=${CC}" "CFLAGS=${CFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} -arch x86_64 -isysroot ${IPHONESIMULATOR_SYSROOT}" "CXX=${CXX}" "CXXFLAGS=${CXXFLAGS} -arch x86_64 -isysroot ${IPHONESIMULATOR_SYSROOT}" LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} ${LDFLAGS}" "LIBS=${LIBS}"
        make -j${JOBS}
        make install
    )
fi

echo "$(tput setaf 2)"
echo "##################"
echo "# armv7 for iPhone"
echo "##################"
echo "$(tput sgr0)"

if [ "${BUILD_IOS_ARMV7}" == "YES" ]
then
    (
        cd ${MIMETIC_SRC_DIR}
        make distclean
        ./configure --build=x86_64-apple-${DARWIN} --host=armv7-apple-${DARWIN} --disable-shared --prefix=${PREFIX} --exec-prefix=${PREFIX}/platform/armv7-ios "CC=${CC}" "CFLAGS=${CFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} -arch armv7 -isysroot ${IPHONEOS_SYSROOT}" "CXX=${CXX}" "CXXFLAGS=${CXXFLAGS} -arch armv7 -isysroot ${IPHONEOS_SYSROOT}" LDFLAGS="-arch armv7 -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} ${LDFLAGS}" "LIBS=${LIBS}"
        make -j${JOBS}
        make install
    )
fi

echo "$(tput setaf 2)"
echo "###################"
echo "# armv7s for iPhone"
echo "###################"
echo "$(tput sgr0)"

if [ "${BUILD_IOS_ARMV7S}" == "YES" ]
then
    (
        cd ${MIMETIC_SRC_DIR}
        make distclean
        ./configure --build=x86_64-apple-${DARWIN} --host=armv7s-apple-${DARWIN} --disable-shared --prefix=${PREFIX} --exec-prefix=${PREFIX}/platform/armv7s-ios "CC=${CC}" "CFLAGS=${CFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} -arch armv7s -isysroot ${IPHONEOS_SYSROOT}" "CXX=${CXX}" "CXXFLAGS=${CXXFLAGS} -arch armv7s -isysroot ${IPHONEOS_SYSROOT}" LDFLAGS="-arch armv7s -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} ${LDFLAGS}" "LIBS=${LIBS}"
        make -j${JOBS}
        make install
    )
fi

echo "$(tput setaf 2)"
echo "##################"
echo "# arm64 for iPhone"
echo "##################"
echo "$(tput sgr0)"

if [ "${BUILD_IOS_ARM64}" == "YES" ]
then
    (
        cd ${MIMETIC_SRC_DIR}
        make distclean
        ./configure --build=x86_64-apple-${DARWIN} --host=arm --disable-shared --prefix=${PREFIX} --exec-prefix=${PREFIX}/platform/arm64-ios "CC=${CC}" "CFLAGS=${CFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} -arch arm64 -isysroot ${IPHONEOS_SYSROOT}" "CXX=${CXX}" "CXXFLAGS=${CXXFLAGS} -arch arm64 -isysroot ${IPHONEOS_SYSROOT}" LDFLAGS="-arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDK_VERSION} ${LDFLAGS}" "LIBS=${LIBS}"
        make -j${JOBS}
        make install
    )
fi

echo "$(tput setaf 2)"
echo "###################################################################"
echo "# Create Universal Libraries and Finalize the packaging"
echo "###################################################################"
echo "$(tput sgr0)"

(
    cd ${PREFIX}/platform
    mkdir universal
    lipo x86_64-sim/lib/${LIBMIMETIC}.a i386-sim/lib/${LIBMIMETIC}.a arm64-ios/lib/${LIBMIMETIC}.a armv7s-ios/lib/${LIBMIMETIC}.a armv7-ios/lib/${LIBMIMETIC}.a -create -output universal/${LIBMIMETIC}.a
)

(
    cd ${PREFIX}
    mkdir bin
    mkdir lib
    cp -r platform/x86_64-mac/lib/* lib
    cp -r platform/universal/* lib
    rm -rf platform
    lipo -info lib/${LIBMIMETIC}.a
)

if [ -d "${PREFIX}-${MIMETIC_VERSION}" ]
then
    rm -rf "${PREFIX}-${MIMETIC_VERSION}"
fi
mv "${PREFIX}" "${PREFIX}-${MIMETIC_VERSION}"

echo Done!
```

Courtesy of ytain of #iphonedev in freenode irc.